# How to fire jQuery actions defined as var multiple times?

Tags: jquery

I have a set of different actions I need to use multiple times. Because of that I am looking for a "shortcode" to call them at different places.

```
var sth_happens = function(){
    $("#red").animate(/* something */);
    $("#green").css({/* something */});
    $("#yellow").css({/* something */});
    .... and so on
}

$("#example").mouseenter(function(){
  // I want to insert the above code here */ 
});

$("#example2").mouseeenter(function(){
  // And here as well
});
```

I know that I could use `var sth_happens = function(){}` like the following, **which is not what I want to do:**

```
var sth_happens = function(){/* Something happens */}
$("sth").click(example_name);
```

To explain **how the code should work:** The following

```
 $("#example").mouseenter(function(){
  // I want to insert the above code here */
  sth_happens(); 
});
$("#example2").mouseenter(function(){
  // I want to insert the above code here */
  sth_happens(); 
});
```

would turn into

```
$("#example").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#red").animate(/* something */);
    $("#green").css({/* something */});
    $("#yellow").css({/* something */});
    .... and so on
});
$("#example2").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#red").animate(/* something */);
    $("#green").css({/* something */});
    $("#yellow").css({/* something */});
    .... and so on
});
```

I hope you are able to understand this question. If not feel free to ask!

Comment: You want to insert with those 3 or more lines of code by just callin `sth_happens()` right?

Comment: @void yes exactly! Its like a professional placeholder, or in less (as css framework) or php a defined variable which you are able to insert whereever you want!

Comment: This is what my code is doing. I am just calling `this_happens()` and the animation works fine like it should.

Comment: What modifications do you want in my code?

Comment: @void I am really sorry, I got stucked in my own examples. Of course your answer is absolutely right. I have started with your code before asking this question with an missing `( )`. Because of that it did not work for me. You have implemented `$this` to append my code on the target-element, which was more then I need. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var this_happens = function(ele){
        ele.animate({"margin-left": "50px", "width": "100px"});
        ele.css({"background-color":"green"});

    }

    $("#red").mouseenter(function(){
        this_happens($(this)); 
    });
});
```

`$(this)` was not defined their. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bjjsmmr/7/)

Comment: Hey @void thanks a lot for your answer, but I think you got me wrong. "this" was just an example, i did not mean the query-term "this". You can replace it with whatever name you want. I have updated my question, hopefully that way it is a bit easier to understand!

Comment: Okay @MarianRick, You saw the fiddle i attached in my answer. It is a set of actions which is being executed. Just have a look at it once.

Comment: I have read and understood your suggestion, but it was not the one I am looking for (or I am not able to adopt this to my needs). I have updated my question, so that it will become a little bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the scope of `this` within your `this_happens` function is not the same as that in the jQuery handler. You need to give the function to the handler by reference:

```
$("#red").mouseenter(this_happens);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4bjjsmmr/4/)

Alternatively, if you want to keep the anonymous function you would either need to supply `this` as a parameter, or change the scope of the function using `call()`:

```
$("#red").mouseenter(function(){
    this_happens.call(this);
});
```

Comment: Hey @Rory thanks a lot for your answer, but I think you got me wrong. "this" was just an example, i did not mean the query-term "this". You can replace it with whatever name you want. I have updated my question, hopefully that way it is a bit easier to understand!

Comment: Ok, then can you explain what you are trying to achieve as it currently is not clear. The above is certainly the issue with your fiddle example.

Comment: maybe I cut my question too short, because I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. I have updated my question, hopefully this time it is easier to understand!